# Template Matching using GPUimage

Tags: ios, image-processing, gpuimage, template-matching

I am developing a iOS Application which is processing an image to find a part of an image which match a template image. The same is implemented using OpenCV but current implementation of OpenCV doesn't supports iOS GPU.

I am new to GPUImage framework so I need to know whether it is possible to do this using GPUImage ? If it is possible, How ?

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this?